# PDFhtml with column-count css proprety

Tags: c#, itext, pdfhtml

I have an HTML content that is using css proprety `column-count:2;`. I was expecting to get the columns in my generated PDF, but instead, I got only one, large column.

Here is the converting method:

```
public static byte[] ConvertHtmlToPDF(string sHtmlContent)
        {
            byte[] oPdfFile = null;

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHtmlContent))
                    return null;

                string sMethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

                string FONTS = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"Content\CustomFonts\Inter_Web\itext";

                var oPageSize = PageSize.A6;


                var fontProvider = new iText.Html2pdf.Resolver.Font.DefaultFontProvider();
                fontProvider.AddDirectory(FONTS);

                ConverterProperties oConverterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
                oConverterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
                iText.StyledXmlParser.Css.Media.MediaDeviceDescription oMediaDeviceDesc = new iText.StyledXmlParser.Css.Media.MediaDeviceDescription(iText.StyledXmlParser.Css.Media.MediaType.PRINT, oPageSize.GetWidth(), oPageSize.GetHeight());
                oConverterProperties.SetMediaDeviceDescription(oMediaDeviceDesc);


                using (MemoryStream oDocumentStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter oDocumentWriter = new PdfWriter(oDocumentStream).SetSmartMode(true))
                    {
                        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(oDocumentWriter);

                        pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(oPageSize);

                        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(sHtmlContent, pdfDocument, oConverterProperties);
                    }

                    oPdfFile = oDocumentStream.ToArray();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return oPdfFile;
        }
```

This is what it look like:

[image]

I can't find anything in the documentation or in SO.

Is it possible to achive this and if positive, how can I change my code to support the `column-count`?

Comment: column-count CSS property is due to be included in early 2022 (not there yet)

Comment: @AndréLemos where can I consult this information? Is there a release date?

Comment: if all goes according to plan, should be October 2022

Comment: @AndréLemos is this still on track?

Comment: no @KevinLee, it got pushed to 2023, as we had requests from customers that took priority. I'm sorry for this.